# Databricks version 7.0 not behaving like version 6.3: class java.lang.Long cannot be cast to class java.lang.Integer

Tags: azure-databricks, azure-synapse

I have a working notebook at azure databricks version 6.3 - Spark 2.4.4

This notebook does ingestions into Azure Synapse Analytics using it's connector

When I upgraded the notebook to version 7.0 - Spark 3.0.0, the process begun to fail with the following error:

> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException:
> HdfsBridge::recordReaderFillBuffer - Unexpected error encountered
> filling record reader buffer: ClassCastException: class java.lang.Long
> cannot be cast to class java.lang.Integer (java.lang.Long and
> java.lang.Integer are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
> [ErrorCode = 106000] [SQLState = S0001]

This is the table schema in the Synapse Analytics:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[IncrementalDestination]
(
[Id] [int] NOT NULL,
[VarChar] [varchar](1000) NULL,
[Char] [char](1000) NULL,
[Text] [varchar](1000) NULL,
[NVarChar] [nvarchar](1000) NULL,
[NChar] [nchar](1000) NULL,
[NText] [nvarchar](1000) NULL,
[Date] [date] NULL,
[Datetime] [datetime] NULL,
[Datetime2] [datetime2](7) NULL,
[Smalldatetime] [smalldatetime] NULL,
[Bigint] [bigint] NULL,
[Bit] [bit] NULL,
[Decimal] [decimal](18, 0) NULL,
[Int] [int] NULL,
[Money] [money] NULL,
[Numeric] [numeric](18, 0) NULL,
[Smallint] [smallint] NULL,
[Smallmoney] [smallmoney] NULL,
[Tinyint] [tinyint] NULL,
[Float] [float] NULL,
[Real] [real] NULL,
[Column With Space] [varchar](1000) NULL,
[Column_ç_$pecial_char] [varchar](1000) NULL,
[InsertionDateUTC] [datetime] NOT NULL,
[De_LastUpdated] [datetime2](3) NOT NULL
)
WITH
(
DISTRIBUTION = ROUND_ROBIN,
CLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE INDEX
)
GO
```

This is the schema generated by Databricks after reading a bunch of parquets in the Azure BlobStorage

```
root
 |-- Id: long (nullable = true)
 |-- VarChar: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Char: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Text: string (nullable = true)
 |-- NVarChar: string (nullable = true)
 |-- NChar: string (nullable = true)
 |-- NText: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Date: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |-- Datetime: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |-- Datetime2: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |-- Smalldatetime: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |-- Bigint: long (nullable = true)
 |-- Bit: boolean (nullable = true)
 |-- Decimal: long (nullable = true)
 |-- Int: long (nullable = true)
 |-- Money: double (nullable = true)
 |-- Numeric: long (nullable = true)
 |-- Smallint: long (nullable = true)
 |-- Smallmoney: double (nullable = true)
 |-- Tinyint: long (nullable = true)
 |-- Float: double (nullable = true)
 |-- Real: double (nullable = true)
 |-- Column_With_Space: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Column_ç_$pecial_char: string (nullable = true)
 |-- InsertionDateUTC: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |-- De_LastUpdated: timestamp (nullable = false)
```

I saw this

```
Int: long (nullable = true)
```

But what can I do?

Shouldn't this conversion be natural and easily done?

I think something broke with these new features =]

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this is caused by following change, as [described in migration guide](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.0/sql-migration-guide.html#ddl-statements):

> In Spark 3.0, when inserting a value into a table column with a different data type, the type coercion is performed as per ANSI SQL standard. Certain unreasonable type conversions such as converting string to int and double to boolean are disallowed. **A runtime exception is thrown if the value is out-of-range for the data type of the column.** In Spark version 2.4 and below, type conversions during table insertion are allowed as long as they are valid Cast. When inserting an out-of-range value to an integral field, the low-order bits of the value is inserted(the same as Java/Scala numeric type casting). For example, if 257 is inserted to a field of byte type, the result is 1. The behavior is controlled by the option `spark.sql.storeAssignmentPolicy`, with a default value as “ANSI”. Setting the option as “Legacy” restores the previous behavior.

So you may try to set `spark.sql.storeAssignmentPolicy` to `Legacy` and re-run the code.

Comment: It looks like you found the ground, but Im curious, my testing flow is: sqlserver table -> parquet -> databricks -> dw table. The sql server table and dw table are the same. I don't see how there could lead to a out of range exception

Comment: I found that my extraction process is transforming int to long, but sadly, spark.conf.set("spark.sql.storeAssignmentPolicy", "Legacy") didn't work